# Merge multiple SQL rows into single JSON object

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

How can i merge multiple rows to a single JSON/JS Object?

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    properties.*,
    landlord.*,
    tenants.*
FROM
    properties
 JOIN landlord_properties
 JOIN property_tenants
 JOIN users landlord ON landlord.id = landlord_properties.landlord_id
  JOIN users tenants ON tenants.id = property_tenants.user_id
  WHERE properties.id = 1
```

Which gives me a 2 row result, because the given property has 2 tenants,

when i run the query on my node server with the mysql node.js package, i get 2 object array, which are exactly the same, except of the tenants key.

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    properties:
     { id: 1,
       name: 'Mr Popper'
       created_at: 2018-03-07T06:29:41.000Z,
       updated_at: 2018-03-07T08:14:25.000Z },
    landlord:
     { id: 194,
       name: 'Mr Example'
       date_created: 2018-03-06T11:37:46.000Z,
       date_updated: 2018-03-06T11:37:46.000Z },
    tenants:
     { id: 193,
       name: 'Mr T'
       date_created: 2018-03-06T11:30:58.000Z,
       date_updated: 2018-03-06T11:30:58.000Z } },
  RowDataPacket {
    properties:
              { id: 1,
       name: 'Mr Popper'
       created_at: 2018-03-07T06:29:41.000Z,
       updated_at: 2018-03-07T08:14:25.000Z },
    landlord:
     { id: 194,
       name: 'Mr Example'
       date_created: 2018-03-06T11:37:46.000Z,
       date_updated: 2018-03-06T11:37:46.000Z }
    tenants:
    { id: 195,
       name: 'Mr Potato'
       date_created: 2018-03-06T11:30:58.000Z,
       date_updated: 2018-03-06T11:30:58.000Z } } } ]
```

Is there a way to merge those objects into one so it the tenants key will be an array of objects without making multiple SQL queries?

Desired data model:

```
[ {
      id: 1,
       name: 'Mr Popper'
       created_at: 2018-03-07T06:29:41.000Z,
       updated_at: 2018-03-07T08:14:25.000Z,
    landlord : {
       id: 194,
       name: 'Mr Example'
       date_created: 2018-03-06T11:37:46.000Z,
       date_updated: 2018-03-06T11:37:46.000Z },
    tenants : [
      { 
        id: 193,
        name: 'Mr T'
        date_created: 2018-03-06T11:30:58.000Z,
        date_updated: 2018-03-06T11:30:58.000Z 
      },
      { 
        id: 195,
        name: 'Mr Potato'
        date_created: 2018-03-06T11:30:58.000Z,
        date_updated: 2018-03-06T11:30:58.000Z 
      }       
    ]
  }]
```

Comment: Show a sample of the desired output.  And clarify - are we attempting to modify the MySQL query to get the desired result, or modify the Node.js / provide code to modify it after retrieval? Lastly, if it's a request to modify the query, please see [providing a MySQL MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333953/870729).

Comment: why is this tagged with `javascript`? i think you should use another `sql` query instead of merging both entries on js side